# Jupyter-lab pyplot cell re-evaluation breaks interactive widget display

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

This code works as expected on a cleanly started kernel, but on re-executing the second cell, instead of an interactive widget (ipypml per https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/users/interactive.html ), I get just the text output as in the image.

How are jupyter, jupyter-lab, widgets, pyplot, and matplotlib interacting to cause this problem?

And how do I properly do a plot so that I can re-execute the cell without re-starting the kernel?

Cell 0:

```
%matplotlib widget
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Cell 1:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(num=0)
ax.plot(np.arange(4))
```

Cell 1 output:

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x161b913a0>]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that I need to make sure the figure gets cleanly opened (or closed and re-opened) in each update.  I had used the `plt.subplots(num=0)` option to keep repeated updates from creating new, non-displayed figures.  (note that the 2nd cell in the screenshot has a been re-executed 5 times and has a [6] prefix)

```
plt.close(0)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(num=0)
ax.plot(np.arange(4))
```

[image]